# Microsoft office

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft

I'm new user and I use linux ubuntu about one week. how can I install microsoft office on ubuntu? I see in web sites that I must install samba first but I can't install it. thanks for your helping.

Comment: Samba has nothing to do with MS Office.

Comment: Samba is for sharing files on a network between a mix of Linux-based and Windows-based computers.  Expanding on Jos' answer, if a web site is telling you that Samba is related Microsoft Office, then you need to look at another web site as the one you're looking at is misleading you...

Answer (score 0):

you can install WPS http://wps-community.org/ who's goal is to bridge the gap it does an infinitely better job than libre office which comes pre-packed with ubuntu which did a better job that open office before it.

(that being said both of them work fine too)

it is, to me, the best solution.

though honorable mentions are :

- running microsoft office through virtualbox
- google drive

also, yeah as Jos pointed out, samba has indeed absolutely nothing to do getting with microsoft office to run on ubuntu.

Comment: There is also Libreoffice and Openoffice.  I think the former is now the default Office for Ubuntu.

Comment: I guess you didn't read my answer at all.